# Adding text to div moves text upward

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add text to my div but whenever I add text it moves some of the text upward off of the screen. I have to adjust the margin-top every time that I add text to the div to correct this. Is there any way to make the text only expand downward when I add text so I don't need to keep adjusting the margin-top?

https://jsfiddle.net/2ey21qj5/4/

```
div.test {
    margin-top:0cm;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: grey;
    top: 5cm;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` and position your text as you want. Or give it `0` arguments: `transform: translate(0,0);`